# tableadapter failed constraints

Tags: c#, sql, exception, constraints, tableadapter

I'm using a tableadapter in a large project and I keep getting the "Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints." error whenever I call any of my queries on it. I do not have null values and I do have unique primary key values in the result set.  Nevertheless, I have tried setting EnforceConstraints to False everywhere in the generated source.   I also removed any primary keys using "delete key" option in the context menu for the column.   I set AllowDBNull true for all the columns in the tableadapter. The exception still occurs.   I have three queries defined under the tableadapter all of which return the same exact same columns (the SQL differs only in the filter expressions used).  Researching this issue online, I found the suggestion to set a try/catch in the generated source code to examine the error to determine the exact cause.   When I do this, no error is generated at all.   The generated source is as follows:

```
public virtual CyberevToo.ReactionImagesDataTable AllMedia(string MindfileID, string FilePath) {
        this.Adapter.SelectCommand = this.CommandCollection[1];
        if ((MindfileID == null)) {
            throw new global::System.ArgumentNullException("MindfileID");
        }
        else {
            this.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[0].Value = ((string)(MindfileID));
        }
        if ((FilePath == null)) {
            throw new global::System.ArgumentNullException("FilePath");
        }
        else {
            this.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[1].Value = ((string)(FilePath));
        }
        CyberevToo.ReactionImagesDataTable dataTable = new CyberevToo.ReactionImagesDataTable();
        this.Adapter.Fill(dataTable);
        return dataTable;
    }
```

The exception is thrown on the "this.Adapter.Fill(dataTable);" line.  After modification, the source code is as follows:

```
 public virtual CyberevToo.ReactionImagesDataTable AllMedia(string MindfileID, string FilePath) {
        this.Adapter.SelectCommand = this.CommandCollection[1];
        if ((MindfileID == null)) {
            throw new global::System.ArgumentNullException("MindfileID");
        }
        else {
            this.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[0].Value = ((string)(MindfileID));
        }
        if ((FilePath == null)) {
            throw new global::System.ArgumentNullException("FilePath");
        }
        else {
            this.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[1].Value = ((string)(FilePath));
        }
        CyberevToo.ReactionImagesDataTable dataTable = new CyberevToo.ReactionImagesDataTable();
        try
        {
          this.Adapter.Fill(dataTable);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex) {
          System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return dataTable;
    }
```

with a breakpoint set on the line "System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);" which never gets reached.  With the try/catch in place, the DataTable is returned fine and full of data.  Without it, no data is returned at all. When I build and run the program with the try/catch, no exception occurs.  When it executes without a try/catch, it fails with the above exception.

Any ideas WHY?   I don't want to have to re-code the generated code for all 20 something tableadapters I have in the XSD every time I make a change to one of the definitions!

Comment: Welcome to the world of typed datasets.  Aka, time wasting.  99% of the time you will either have a missing/mispelled column in the resultset....OR a null where null is not allowed in the xsd.  How do debug?  Create a "View" that does a select top 100 * from dbo.YourActualTable ORDER BY SomeKey.   Start with a high number "select top 100"....then if that still fails...dwindle it down (like "select top 50")...if that works then dwindle up, if it fails, dwindle down.  keep dwindling til you find the magic row..and see what is different about it.  probably a null.

Comment: Obviously, populate the DataSet/DataTable using the View.

Comment: There is no null value and the dataset displays fine with the full 100+ rows so long as the try/catch is there.  The sql server management studio results match the dataset results exactly, row for row and column for column.